# Sidebar always hidden on HTML5UP prologue/Skeljs framework

Tags: jquery, css, javascript-framework

I use HTML5up Prologue based on the skeljs framework.
http://html5up.net/uploads/demos/prologue/

I want my menu navigation on the left always hidden like in the narrow view (<961pixels).
The toggle div always shown.
Like here: http://getskel.com/demos/offcanvasnav.html

the code for this is in the init.js
http://html5up.net/uploads/demos/prologue/js/init.js

```
(function($) {

skel.init({
    reset: 'full',
    breakpoints: {
        'global':   { range: '*', href: 'css/style.css', containers: 1400, grid: { gutters: 40 }, viewport: { scalable: false } },
        'wide':     { range: '961-1880', href: 'css/style-wide.css', containers: 1200, grid: { gutters: 40 } },
        'normal':   { range: '961-1620', href: 'css/style-normal.css', containers: 960, grid: { gutters: 40 } },
        'narrow':   { range: '961-1320', href: 'css/style-narrow.css', containers: '100%', grid: { gutters: 20 } },
        'narrower': { range: '-960', href: 'css/style-narrower.css', containers: '100%', grid: { gutters: 15 } },
        'mobile':   { range: '-736', href: 'css/style-mobile.css', grid: { collapse: true } }
    },
    plugins: {
        layers: {
            sidePanel: {
                hidden: true,
                breakpoints: 'narrower',
                position: 'top-left',
                side: 'left',
                animation: 'pushX',
                width: 240,
                height: '100%',
                clickToHide: true,
                html: '<div data-action="moveElement" data-args="header"></div>',
                orientation: 'vertical'
            },
            sidePanelToggle: {
                breakpoints: 'narrower',
                position: 'top-left',
                side: 'top',
                height: '4em',
                width: '5em',
                html: '<div data-action="toggleLayer" data-args="sidePanel" class="toggle"></div>'
            }
        }
    }
});
```

I tried to add more breakpoints in the layers sidePanel/sidepanelToggle definition but was unsuccessful. Can you point me in the right direction how to add more breakpoints in the layer definition, or is this the wrong way?

Answer (score 1):

I managed to keep the sidebar hidden by making a couple modifications in your files.
- in that javascript you posted, I've commented out the breakpoints on both the sidePanel and the sidePanelToggle
- in the main html file I made sure the following div was showing in the right place

```
<div data-action="toggleLayer" data-args="sidePanel" 
   class="toggle" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); cursor: pointer;"></div>
```

You can view my results on [this link](http://goo.gl/beZLbT)

Comment: Looks good, on your site....
I have problems where to put the toggleLayer **DIV**, because of the generated source code.
You added that **toggleLayer DIV** just before the closing **BODY**?

Comment: Your link is working properly, but your toggle div has no content... try adding this to your css:
    #sidePanelToggle .toggle:before { content: '\f0c9' }

You can also add content to this div directly in the Html